# Unable to get response in for loop from cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cheerio

I am trying to use cheerio to scrape some data from a website but i collect some [href]s and then I again want to request those link and get some data However I getting all the links but when for loop is executed, I am unable to see the html from those pages.
What am I missing?

```
var express=require('express');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var port =8080;
var cheerioTableparser = require('cheerio-tableparser');
var Links = [];
var uniqueLinks = [];
var url = "http://getThoseLinks.com";
var count = 2;
app.get('/',function (req,res) {
  request(url, function (error, response, html) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        var url2 = "http://getThoseLinks.com?pager=true&paged="+i;
    request(url2,function (err,res,body) {
       var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            cheerioTableparser($);
            var data = $(".Q-grid").parsetable(false, false, false);
            console.log(data.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i=i+4) {
                var regex = /<a href="(.*?)"/g;
                while (match = regex.exec(data[0][i])) {
                    console.log(match[1]);// **this gets printed**
                    request(url+match[1],function (errLink,resLink,htmlData) {
                      var $ = cheerio.load(htmlData);
                      console.log($); // **This does not**
                    })
                }
            }
    });
  };
 uniqueLinks=Links.filter(function(item, i, ar){ return ar.indexOf(item) === i; });
  for (var i = 0; i < uniqueLinks.length; i++) {
        data= "http://getThoseLinks.com" + uniqueLinks[i];
        console.log(data);
    }
 }
else
{
console.log(error);
}
});
});

app.listen(port);
exports= module.exports= app;

console.log('server running on '+port);
```

Comment: Did you try logging `htmlData` variable to ensure html is being returned properly?

Comment: Yes I did but its giving me the same html result from first for loop....in first for loop, I try to get all links and then in second for loop trying to go to those links...but its not changing the html data so var htmlData is same as html from first request.

Comment: I'd switch to a modern promise-based request library to avoid callback hell and await everythng so you can get your results easily.